# SQL Server 2019 Criteria Pane filter function for filter datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]I could like to ask about inside the SQL Server 2019 Criteria Pane filter function.
I have a date table call 'SODueDate' and I would like to filter the date ='2023-04-26 00:00:00.000'. But Once I enter the filter ='2023-04-26 00:00:00.000', system pop error for me. Did anyone one know what should I put to make the date filter. Thank!

Looking for the ways for filter the Date inside Microsoft SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Is there error pop-up that you're getting relating to conversion of varchar to datetime?  I think you'll find that if you just enter ='2023-04-26' or even ='2023-04-26 0:00' then it will be OK.  It's about the editor trying to do a data conversion, and it can't convert when you've got the seconds and milliseconds.  If you do really need seconds and milliseconds, then you'll have to actually enter the criteria as =CONVERT(datetime, '2023-04-26 13:23:44.234') ... you'll probably get an error about CONVERT being unnecessary, but it will still work

Comment: I see, it work!
Btw, is it possible if I make it filter like between '2023-04-25 00:00:00.000' to  '2023-04-26 13:23:44.234'

Comment: Hi @Ray, you'd need to enter a "between" condition into the "Filter" text-box as something like >=2023-04-25 AND <=CONVERT(datetime, '2023-04-25 13:23:44.234')